# What did I miss in my code to cause Attribute value must be constant

Tags: java, annotations

I've been at this for hours and from what I'm seeing it should be possible but I keep getting the error ***"Attribute value must be constant"***

I've been looking at many posts here but not seeing what my issue is.

In my test class file

```
// The annotation
@Pattern(regexp = MetaFilters.FuzzyDate.getRegExp())
```

.
In the enum file

```
public enum MetaFilters {
    FuzzyDate;
    private String regExp;

    static {
        FuzzyDate.regExp = "...a pattern...";
    }

    public String getRegExp() {
        return regExp;
    }
}
```

I've tried writing the enum more ways than I can recall at this point. The whole purpose of this is to have many regular expression options as the pattern may have only YYYY-MM-DD or may include a timestamp or could be a different format for the date itself. Please provide some guidance.

So what am I missing here in order to get this to work?

Comment: The annotation attribute must be a compile-time constant, i.e. a String literal, or a static final String. You can't call a method like you're doing to obtain the annotation value.

Comment: @JBNizet so are you saying it cannot be done or that it cannot be done the way I'm trying to do it? If the later, how can I approach it to make it work? Thanks.

Comment: It can't be done.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Greatly appreciated.